# Can web service access Server hard disk

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-3.0

I face a situation where my web service needs to access partion D in server hard disk and can send, receive files to/from client.

Is it true that a web service can do that even when there's no permission on the folder?

I know that I can add to the folder of asp.net path using mappath function...

Can any one illustrate to me how this would be done and how can the web service access the server local disk?

Comment: I think if you have ASP.NET running in Full Trust mode, it will work if the user running the ASP.NET process has access to that file. If both of those assumptions aren't true, then you won't be able to access the files via ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the web service to be able to either read or write files to a folder on your server it must have permission to do so.

The first question you need to determine is what user is the web service executing under?  Once you know that then you can set the appropriate rights to the folder in question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It should have been a comment.

Comment: @Mufasa:? my first sentence answers the first AND second question by the OP..  my second sentence gives him/her a hint as to what look for in order to make it work.

Comment: "Can any one illustrate to me how this would be done and how can the web service access the server local disk?" was not answered.

Comment: @ChrisLively what about webapplication\]

Answer (score -1):

"Is it true that a web service can do that even when there's no permission on the folder?"

NO